# How can I add my product key permanently to a Windows 10 install USB drive?

Tags: windows-10, installation, bootable-media, license, dism

Good evening,

I am trying to activate a Windows 10 IoT Enterprise CBB install permanently with its license key by using the DISM tool.

I have found [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/808487/how-can-i-add-my-license-key-to-my-usb-windows-7-install) which explains how to do it (mounting the install.wim, setting the product key and unmounting the install.wim). I am doing the same steps, however when installing Windows to a drive, it still prompts me the Product Key dialog box also with EULAs.

My product key is valid and the purpose of this operation is to install my Windows 10 Edition in "one-shot" which means without typing any license key or accepting any EULAs since they would have been already typed/accepted.

(I am using a bootable USB drive in UEFI)

Comment: Apart from the answer below you may also need to look at using an unattend file if you expect to have an automated installation.

Answer (score 14):

> Use notepad to make a file called PID.txt and put the following in the
>   file:
>
> ```
> [PID]
> Value=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
> ```
>
> Place your Windows 10 product key in where the X's are and save the
>   file to the /sources directory of your Windows 10 installation USB
>   flash drive.

Source: https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/73339-automatically-add-product-key.html#post899558

Additional sources include Microsoft support for this very process: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-edition-configuration-and-product-id-files--eicfg-and-pidtxt

Comment: Thank you. I added my 2016 Datacenter License to the ISO, and now no more inserting it. You Rock.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Kinnectus works like a charm : adding the PID.txt bypasses the Product Key dialog box.

However as I wanted to customize my image further, I took a look at unattend files as Appleoddity noticed below my question.

Using Windows System Image Manager (WSIM), I also managed to add the product key automatically by customizing the [UserData](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-setup-userdata) component of my image.

Thank you everyone for your help.